# Using fish shell builtins with find exec

Tags: bash, find, virtualenv, fish

I'm trying to `source` a file that I can get from the output of `find` using these commands:

```
find ./ -iname activate.fish -exec source {} \;
```

and

```
find ./ -iname activate.fish -exec builtin source {} \;
```

But both these commands give the error of the form `find: ‘source’: No such file or directory` or `find: ‘builtin’: No such file or directory`. Seems like exec of find is not able to recognize fish's builtins ?

What I basically want to achieve is a single command that will search for Python's virtualenv activate scripts in the current directory and execute them.

So doing something like `-exec fish -c 'source {}; \` would not help. I've tried it as well and it doesn't error out but does not make the changes either.

Any ideas what can be done for this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `source "$(find ./ -iname activate.fish)"` ?

Comment: `find -exec` won't ever change the environment of the calling shell. you have to do something like `source "$(find ./ -iname activate.fish)"`

Comment: Yeah `source (find ./ -iname activate.fish)` does work. Did not know `-exec` does not run in the same environment as current shell. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need:

```bash
for file in (find ./ -iname activate.fish)
  source $file
end

# or
find ./ -iname activate.fish | while read file
  source $file
end
```

[Command substitution](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#command-substitution) executes the command, splits on newlines, and returns that list.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, seems like `-exec` does not run in or affect the current shell environment. So `find -exec` is not gonna work for my use case.

Instead, this will work:

```
source (find ./ -iname activate.fish)
```

Comment: Note: `source` will source one file, and pass any other arguments as $argv. If your `find` finds more than one active.fish, this will break in awkward ways.